# How to dynamically subscribe to an event?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

**RELATED**

- [Watch control to determine events being fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701762/watch-control-to-determine-events-being-fired)

---

I need to detect when an event is fired. To do so I am trying to subscribe dynamically on the event.

The problem is that I have different types of delegates, not all events have the same signature. The solutions provided [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701762/watch-control-to-determine-events-being-fired) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779/c-dynamic-event-subscription) expects `object sender, EventArgs e`, which I am not using, so I get an exception telling the types doesn't match.

Here are some examples of a delegates I have:

```
public delegate void OnEventA(int id);
public delegate void OnEventB(double num, string name);
```

How can I create the correct delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found some articles:

- [How to: Hook Up a Delegate Using Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx)
- [Delegate.CreateDelegate Method (Type, Object, MethodInfo, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3860fy3.aspx)

It helped me to understand what I was trying to do and I should do.

I need to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` passing the `EventHandlerType` (the type of the event, the delegate), a instance of a class and the method info of the method (from the class in the previous parameter) that will handle the event. Target is the control that fires this event.

```
Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(evt.EventHandlerType, abc, mi1, false);
evt.AddEventHandler(target, handler);
```

Further digging lead me to this method. I can subscribe to events using lambda expression. Using [`Action<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781604/passing-a-lambda-to-a-method-with-diferent-parameters) I can subscribe with different types and numbers of parameters.

```
public static Delegate Create<T>(EventInfo e, Action<T> a)
{
    var parameters = e.EventHandlerType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, "p")).ToArray();
    var exp = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(a), a.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"), parameters);
    var l = Expression.Lambda(exp, parameters);
    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(e.EventHandlerType, l.Compile(), "Invoke", false);
}
```

Using this method (e is the EventInfo; EventManager is the class with the static method above)

```
e.AddEventHandler(this, EventManager.Create<int>(e, (x) => Console.WriteLine("Execute")));
```

Answer (score 6):

`EventInfo` has a method `AddEventHandler` that you can use. If you don't have a delegate instance, then you can create a delegate dynamically using `Delegate.CreateDelegate`:

```
var eh = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, target, methodInfo);
ei.AddEventHandler(owner, eh);
```

In this example `target` is the target object for the delegate and `methodInfo` is a `MethodInfo` of a method in the `target` object. Finally, `owner` is the object where the event `ei` belongs.

Comment: Do I need MethodInfo? Can't I use a lambda? What if I need to pass parameters?

Comment: @BrunoLM: You can use lambda in place of `eh` if you know the delegate type (e.g. `EventHandler`). If you don't know this, you'll need to create a new instance of some (your) object, use it in place of `target` and pass parameters to this object in constructor (in this case, method info would be info about some method in this object - you can e.g. define an `Invoke` method).

Comment: More specifically: You could try `OnLoad eh = () => { ... }`. It will work as long as all `Tickable` events are of a delegate type `OnLoad`.

Comment: What if the delegate is different in each case? And what if it have parameters?

Comment: If the delegate is different then you need to create it dynamically using `CreateDelegate`. To provide some parameters, you'll need to create a new object in place of `target`.